# Poor Performance in a multi tasking runner algorithm

Tags: java, performance, concurrency

it seems to me that i get poor performance using the following SupervisedExecutor and ExecutorSuperviser implementation of my own, What do you think can be unefficient in this code? I want to learn how can i improve its effciency.

***ExecutorSuperviser Class:***

```
public class ExecutorSuperviser {
private SupervisedExecutor[] threadPool;
private int poolSize = 0;
private LinkedList<Runnable> q;\\my own implementation of linkedlist
public ExecutorSuperviser(int nThreads) {
    threadPool=new SupervisedExecutor[poolSize=nThreads];
    q=new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    init();
}
public void execute(Runnable r) { 
    synchronized (q) {
        q.addToTail(r);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<poolSize;i++) 
            if (!threadPool[i].isBusy()) {
                if (!threadPool[i].isAlive()) threadPool[i].start();
                threadPool[i].interrupt();
                return;
            }


}
private void init() {
    for (int i=0;i<poolSize;i++) {
        threadPool[i]=new SupervisedExecutor(this);
    }

}
public Object getLock() {
    return q;
}
public Runnable getTask() {
    return q.removeHead();
}
public void terminate() {
    for (int i=0;i<poolSize;i++) 
        threadPool[i].terminate();
}
public void waitUntilFinished() {
    while (!isFinished()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
private boolean isFinished() {
    for (int i=0;i<poolSize;i++) 
        if (threadPool[i].isBusy()) return false;
    return q.isEmpty();
}

}
```

***SupervisedExecutor Class:***

```
public class SupervisedExecutor extends Thread {
    private boolean   terminated = false;
    private Boolean busy = false;
    private ExecutorSuperviser boss;
    SupervisedExecutor (ExecutorSuperviser boss) {
        this.boss=boss;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!terminated) {
            try {
                sleep(MAX_PRIORITY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                synchronized (busy) {
                    busy=true;
                }
                Runnable r;
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (boss.getLock()) {
                        r=boss.getTask();
                    }
                    if (r!=null) r.run();
                    else break;
                } 
                synchronized (busy) {
                    busy=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isBusy() {
        boolean isBusy;
        synchronized (boss.getLock()) {
            isBusy=busy;
        }
        return isBusy;
    }
    public void terminate() {
        terminated=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with the built-in concurrency library e.g. ExecutorService? How is your implementation better?

Comment: i didnt say its better, it just offers what ExecutorService does not, which is the ability to waitUntilFinished(), which means the calling thread can wait untill all runnable that were sent to get executed are finished running... basiclly im just trying to get better in Coding java, so it was just for learnning...

Comment: Instead of waiting to 10 ms, I would try using a state change with wait/notify or use a thread safe queue.

Comment: there are 2 sleeps in the code, one of them is for the calling to waitUntilFinished(), so i assume you arent reffering to it, and the second one is meant to be interrupted...

Comment: Does [awaitTermination][1] does not do what you want? [1]:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: nope. it force you to shutdown the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following solution which has the following advantages:

1. As a subclass of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29), you don't have to re-implement everything which `ThreadPoolExecutor` does for you just to get the `waitUntilFinished()` functionality that you're after.
2. By taking advantage of `ReentrantLock`, `Condition`, and `await()`/`signal()` you avoid busy waiting, which can certainly hurt performance.

This implementation works by taking advantage of the `beforeExecute()` and `afterExecute()` methods which `ThreadPoolExecutor` exposes to keep our own count of active tasks. I don't use `getActiveCount()` because, according to the JavaDoc, it doesn't guarantee an exact answer (although perhaps in the case of `ThreadPoolExecutor` it does provide an exact answer, I'd need to research further to be sure).

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class WaitableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor
{
    private Condition waitCondition;
    private ReentrantLock lock;
    private int taskCount = 0;

    public WaitableThreadPoolExecutor( int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue )
    {
        super( corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue );

        lock = new ReentrantLock( );
        waitCondition = lock.newCondition( );
    }

    // if isEmpty() is true, then there is no need to block
    // otherwise, wait until waitCondition is signaled
    public void waitUntilFinished( )
    {
        lock.lock( );
        try
        {
            while ( !isEmpty( ) )
                waitCondition.await( );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock( );
        }
    }

    // the ThreadPool is empty if our taskCount is 0 and the
    // work queue is empty (this may not be bullet-proof, for one
    // thing, I'm hesitant to use getActiveCount() because it
    // does not guarantee an exact answer
    protected boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        lock.lock( );
        try
        {
            return taskCount == 0 && getQueue( ).isEmpty( );
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock( );
        }
    }

    // increment our task count before executing each task
    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute( Thread t, Runnable r )
    {
        super.beforeExecute( t, r );

        lock.lock( );
        try
        {
            taskCount += 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock( );
        }
    }

    // decrement our task count after executing each task
    // then, if the pool is empty, signal anyone waiting
    // on the waitCondition
    @Override
    protected void afterExecute( Runnable r, Throwable t )
    {
        super.afterExecute( r, t );

        lock.lock( );
        try
        {
            taskCount -= 1;

            if ( isEmpty( ) ) waitCondition.signalAll( );
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock( );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        WaitableThreadPoolExecutor pool = new WaitableThreadPoolExecutor( 2, 4, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>( ) );

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            final int threadId = i;

            pool.execute( new Runnable( )
            {
                @Override
                public void run( )
                {
                    try { Thread.sleep( (int) ( Math.random( ) * 5000 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }

                    System.out.println( threadId + " done." );
                }
            });
        }

        pool.waitUntilFinished( );

        System.out.println( "Done waiting." );
    }
}
```

I included a simple `main()` method which you can use as a test case. It starts 10 threads which wait a random amount of time before printing that they are done. Then the main thread calls `waitUntilFinished()`.

The results will look something like (the main point being that `Done waiting.` will always be printed last:

```
1 done.
2 done.
0 done.
4 done.
3 done.
5 done.
7 done.
8 done.
6 done.
9 done.
Done waiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find using the plain ExecutorService shorter and easier.

Note: This is ALL the code you need.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

List<Future<Void>>futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int threadId = i;
    futures.add(es.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
            System.out.println(threadId + " done.");
            return null;
        }
    }));
}
for (Future<Void> future : futures)
    future.get();
System.out.println("Done waiting.");

es.shutdown();
```

prints

```
2 done.
4 done.
7 done.
6 done.
8 done.
5 done.
9 done.
1 done.
3 done.
0 done.
Done waiting.
```